# Windows Installer - No repair is triggered with .NET (assembly files) keyfiles are deleted

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I created a windows Installer MSI package that installs assembly binaries (exe) with their libraries (dll), each set with their own keyfiles. When I delete an assembly binary or a resource files, it does not trigger a repair? The same installer with Win32 binary and resource files repairs everytime?

Comment: If your installer is properly set up with a single binary per component with key paths defined and you are invoking the main application EXE via an advertised shortcut, then self-repair should work just fine regardless of whether the files are win32 or .NET. Are you testing with two different installers? I bet you are not using a proper advertised shortcut for your .NET install, or you have put the advertised shortcut in a feature by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair and Resilency have slightly different meanings.  Repair is invoked ( like through Add/Remove Programs ) and Resilency is triggered.

Common triggers for resilency are advertised shortcuts and COM activation. When resilency is triggered, it will invoke a repair on the entire primary feature that the corrupt component belongs to.

Since your .NET, it's unlikely you are using COM.  Use an Advertised shortcut for the EXE and put all of the components in the same feature. If this doesn't work, there are also ways of calling the MSI API via an interop library in your code to perform your own custom health check and invoke repair.